# Connection Timeout but Job still running

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis, timeout

I have a IIS website going for internal job processing. the job will take about 10 mins. When the user click the button to start the job, after about a minute the whole page whipe white and showing "Connection Timeout". However the job is related to calling 3rd pty APIs, they are still going underground.

When the job is still running, the user cannot log back to the website. After the job is finished, the user can use the website again.

Is there any secret here?

Answer (score 0):

You have several things in play here.

1. time web browser will wait for a response
2. Time the webserver will process a request
3. Time the sql command will execute before the client times out.
4. time the SQL server will run a command before it terminates the command.

Typically the webbrowser one is a minute or two (not sure of exact numbers)
see: [connection timeout in IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050)
see: in firefox  you should be able to check about:config

For the webserver and asp.net see [HttpRuntimeSection.ExecutionTimeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout.aspx)

command timeout see [Sqlcommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) the default is 30 seconds.

That being said... just because the client stops waiting doesn't force sql server to stop running the command.  Calling close on the connection should stop the running command on the server, however you may need to wait for it to rollback any changes it may have made.

I suspect you are not using sql server agent jobs but if you are then disconnecting your connection will not stop the job.

if it is just a client not waiting for you to send output then what you could  do is send some output to the client...

like

```
  Response.Write("<!-- progress ... -->");
  Response.Flush();
```

You have to flush so that it doesn't buffer the response on the server side

Comment: Thanks. Let me specify the real situation: in the server side c# code we had a circulation sending for example 400 objects to a remote API call. the page shows connection timeout but the server code is still running. let's exclude SQL issue.